# How to pass unique data from csv file into jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using the jmeter for load testing a web application.I am using csv Data Set Config to pass email to test login scenario.While i am running with 100 concurrent users,it is picking same email from csv file.How can i make sure that it will use one email only once.

Comment: How many test data you have in CSV file? In  CSV Data Set Config, in`Sharing Mode` you can set to `Current Thread Group`. If you need dummy email ID you can send random string using `${__UUID}`

Comment: Also set the `Recycle on EOF`: false, `Stop thread on EOF`: True. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: How many email addresses do you have in your config file? Are you writing a Performance Test or a Functional Automated test? Do you need each user to pick one email address and then consume it and hence is one email associated with each user?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue during concurrency testing using CSV data config. By enabling Sharing Mode=All Threads in CSV data config solved my problem and i was able to send unique data per request
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use [Random String Function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) for generation of different email ids,

RandomString function returns a random String of length using characters in chars to use.
 It has three parameters,

```
1. Length of the desired random string
2. Source characters
3. If you need to store generated string into a JMeter variable you can provide variable name as 3rd argument.
```

`${__RandomString(6,a12zeczclk, MYVAR)}`

Example as,

```
${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@MyMail.com
```

Comment: why -1? for answer